# IE10 sparks a JSON syntax error within dynamic Glimpse scripting

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, internet-explorer, glimpse

Glimpse is awesome. It has been a big help with my MVC endeavors.

I installed [IE10 for Windows 7 Release Preview](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/ie-10-release-preview) and was instantly irritated, forgetting Microsoft would surely force an upgrade rather than a side-by-side install.

Now I'm experiencing syntax errors within dynamically generated Glimpse script... *but only in IE10 and only on a particular view*.

Here's a snippet from the **HTTP request**:

```
GET http://localhost:8200/Glimpse.axd?v=0.87&r=data.js&id=6573e2d4-c1c6-4591-ae89-db544b76bbc4 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/javascript, */*;q=0.8
Referer: http://localhost:8200/employee
```

The culprit is a single character position in the following **JSON object**:

```
[2,"Index","","False","RazorViewEngine","False","True",{"ViewData":{"CurrentEmployee":"System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Employee_2BC4A98778F94213FB61E04B65C365B27A9391A342794A2ED101A9B4EB30B553"},"Model":{"ModelType":"System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<Wims.Web.Models.Employee>","Value":},"TempData":null},"selected"]
```

**Note**: that the "CurrentEmployee" is a dynamic `(Employee)ViewBag.CurrentEmployee` that I pipe from a base controller responsible for authentication/authorization.

The **syntax error** reported is the character index between the JSON pairing colon and its closing curly brace on the Model's "Value" property:

```
"Value":},
```

If I understand JSON correct, this is in fact a syntax error in that even if this dynamic object was null, the JSON should be formed as such: `{"Value":""}`

---

### Question:

`CurrentEmployee` is not null, and the page continues to render - so what is the deal? Why is IE10 the only browser to chime in? Is it causing the script error? Is it the only one that takes notice? Is it Glimpse not handling IE10?

Anyone have an aswer?

Comment: The same syntax error occurs when changing the IE version and standards (`F12`) to earlier versions of IE, including `Quirks` modes.

Answer (score 0):

The Glimpse 1.0 Release Candidate, currently available on NuGet as a prerelease package, should rectify this problem.

I recommend upgrading, and if you still experience this issue, please submit a bug in the [Glimpse issue tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse/issues?direction=desc&sort=created&state=open).